# How to deploy a play framework app and exclude particular resources under "public" directory?

Tags: deployment, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want to deploy a Play 2 application, my javascript and css files are in the "public" directory,  I only want to expose minified javascript files and keep the sources private.  How can I achieve it with Play? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I only want to expose minified javascript files and keep the sources private.

It is very easy. Look at the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/AssetsGoogleClosureCompiler) where it says:

> Any JavaScript file present in app/assets will be parsed by Google Closure compiler, checked for errors and dependencies and minified if activated in the build configuration.

So instead of having the `.js` files in `/public/javascripts/` you place them in `/app/assets/javascripts/` and when the application is built you will have both a `.js` file and a `.min.js` file available.

You don't have to change your `<script/>` tag either, just keep it as it was:

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/my-javascripts.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

or

```
<script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/my-javascripts.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

If you **only** want to allow the `.min.js` files to be accessed then you can update the `routes` file with a regex:

```
GET  /assets/javascripts/$file<.*\.min\.js> controllers.Assets.at(path="/public/javascripts", file)
```

Now you can to to address `http://my.domain.com/assets/javascripts/my-javascript.min.js` but not `http://my.domain.com/assets/javascripts/my-javascript.js`.

Comment: Hi maba, thanks for the reply. With what you desribed, the js sources will still be exposed to the outside world. What I want is to not deploy js sources at all.

Comment: You can do like I suggested and then update the `routes` file to only allow a certain regex pattern. I will update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks maba, thats what i was after, though I need some extra tweeks to make it work for my application as there are other resources I want to keep secret, but I believe what you posted here is the right path to follow. Cheers.

Comment: @JayHuang Great! As you can see in [Assets](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/Assets) in the documentation this solution forces you to do some more coding when using reverse routing for assets.